# Performance issue with joda-time DateTime.with*()

Tags: java, performance, jodatime

Is there any fast way to create DateTime instance and set minutes\seconds\millis to 0?
At this moment I am using the following code:

```
private DateTime createDateTime(java.util.Date date, org.joda.time.Chronology chronology) {
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date, chronology);
    dateTime = dateTime.withMinuteOfHour(0);
    dateTime = dateTime.withSecondOfMinute(0);
    dateTime = dateTime.withMillisOfSecond(0);
    return dateTime;
}
```

But when it invokes about 200.000 times, dateTime.with***(0); takes a lot of time. Probably there is more correct solution?

Answer (score 8):

Maybe like this?

```
// Truncate minutes/seconds/milliseconds from the date's timestamp
long truncatedTimestamp = date.getTime() - date.getTime() % 3600000;
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(truncatedTimestamp, chronology);
```

Why is this faster?

- My solution uses fast integer arithmetic (negligible) and 1 unix timestamp normalisation (expensive) in the `DateTime` constructor
- Your solution uses 1 unix timestamp normalisation (expensive) in the `DateTime` constructor and 3 more normalisations (expensive), every time you set some date part to `0`
- Other solutions may need less lines of code, but when you look at JodaTime sources, they require even more than 3 normalisations (expensive)

Hence, you probably can't beat modulo.
As others pointed out, this might lead to incorrect results in very remote corner-cases where hours don't count 60 seconds (e.g. due to leap seconds), although I fail to see how, as the unix timestamp can always be truncated to zero, to get the beginning of a calendar hour (examples welcome).

Comment: There aren't a fixed number of seconds in a minute, so on some occasions this would be wrong.

Comment: Is arithmetic, especially Modulo calculation faster than 3 set method? Also, date.getTime(), u did that twice, so 2 getters and a calculation, is that really faster than 3 setters? And since he is settting hours to 0, shouldn't it be also, 3600000*24

Comment: @Churk: Don't worry about these minor things. What's expensive in the `with` method is the complete date-time arithmetic. Note, the OP is not setting hours to `0`

Comment: @Dunes: True in some remote cases. But if that has to be taken into account, then it's hard to speed things up massively...

Comment: @LukasEder Why are u asking me this question when I didn't say truncating minutes would leads to wrong results. I pointed out that you need to do this for the hours also since the OP wanted a date, not date with hours.

Comment: @Dunes: Actually, can you provide an example where truncating minutes on a unix timestamp leads to wrong results? I fail to see how this can happen... Leap seconds are "stolen" or "added" by removing, repeating some unix timestamps in the "time-continuum"

Comment: Sorry @Churk. I meant to ask Dunes. Still, the OP is not setting hours to `0`, only minutes...

Comment: Nevermind, I made a mistake. The unix epoch does not represent leap seconds, so the problem would never occur.

Answer (score 5):

Just tried the code below - it **looks** like method 1 (yours) takes about 320ms on my pc, vs method 2 (mine) 390ms, vs method 3 (Lukas's) 15ms, vs method 4 (MutableDateTime) 310ms... Now the modulo might (?) lead to incorrect results.

```
public class Test {

    private static int NUM_RUN;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Date date = new Date();
        List<Runnable> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(method3Withs(date));
        list.add(method1With(date));
        list.add(methodModulo(date));
        list.add(methodMutable(date));

        NUM_RUN = 100_000;
        for (Runnable r : list) {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            r.run();
            long end = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println((end - start) / 1000000);
        }

        NUM_RUN = 10_000_000;
        for (Runnable r : list) {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            r.run();
            long end = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println((end - start) / 1000000);
        }
    }

    private static Runnable method3Withs(final Date date) {
        return new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                DateTime d2 = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RUN; i++) {
                    d2 = new DateTime(date);
                    d2 = d2.withMinuteOfHour(0);
                    d2 = d2.withSecondOfMinute(0);
                    d2 = d2.withMillisOfSecond(0);
                }
                System.out.println(d2);
            }
        };
    }

    private static Runnable method1With(final Date date) {
        return new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                DateTime d2 = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RUN; i++) {
                    d2 = new DateTime(date);
                    d2 = d2.withTime(d2.getHourOfDay(), 0, 0, 0);
                }
                System.out.println(d2);
            }
        };
    }
    private static Runnable methodModulo(final Date date) {
        return new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                DateTime d2 = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RUN; i++) {
                    long truncatedTimestamp = date.getTime() - date.getTime() % 3600000;
                    d2 = new DateTime(truncatedTimestamp);
                }
                System.out.println(d2);
            }
        };
    }

    private static Runnable methodMutable(final Date date) {
        return new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MutableDateTime m = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RUN; i++) {
                    m = new MutableDateTime(date);
                    m.setMinuteOfHour(0);
                    m.setSecondOfMinute(0);
                    m.setMillisOfSecond(0);
                }
                System.out.println(m);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I made it 10 million runs after a warm up round of 100,000:

> 3037
>   4068
>   88
>   2864

The modulo method wins by a large margin, so it seems safe to think it will perform much better in most situations.

Comment: @artbristol Yes I know which is why I emphasised **looks like** ;)

Comment: The input parameter is for `java.util.Date`, not `DateTime`

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a `MutableDateTime`: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Using_a_MutableDateTime, then call `toDateTime()` on it

Answer (score 3):

The method `dateTime.hourOfDay().roundFloorCopy()` should round the minute, second and milli to zero in a single method call (and is the recommended way if performance is not an issue). However, it is unlikely to be faster than calling modulo on the millis directly.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `withTime()` method of class `DateTime`, so that you only have to do one call?

```
private DateTime createDateTime(java.util.Date date, org.joda.time.Chronology chronology) {
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date, chronology);
    return dateTime.withTime(dateTime.getHourOfDay(), 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: @assylias Ah yes, I see that's one of your test cases. That's really strange, especially if you look at the source code of Joda Time to see what exactly all those `with...()` methods do.

Comment: Or maybe due to the way I test it which is a bit simplistic!

Comment: It's quite intuitive. Check out the sources: https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/DateTime.java#L736. This runs two date time manipulation operations more than the OP's code